# How return ref var from function

Tags: database, go, row, ref

I just begin to learn Go, and have a problem with returning ref vars from function

I have a function to get rows from a DB table:

```
func getData(query string, db *sql.DB) *sql.Rows {
    rows, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("SQL select error: ")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    return rows
}
```

now I try to get data from db

```
rows := getData("select * from all_obrash", db)
fmt.Println(rows)
```

I expect it just returns `*sql.Rows` but I get nothing

```
&{0xc00025e100 0x4cf270 0xc0002743c0 <nil> 0xc000248180 {{0 0} 0 0 0 0} true <nil> []}
```

When I call from `main()` it works just fine, but when I move code to `func` it stop get rows, I think I miss something here.

Comment: have you properly create db object?

Comment: What do you mean "I get nothing"? Your output is obviously something, _not_ nothing.

Comment: [`sql.Rows`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows) exposes an interface for iterating the result set. Printing the `sql.Rows` itself will get you nothing of value (the same as e.g. printing an `io.Reader` instead of actually reading from it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

defer rows.Close() gets executed when function returns

```
  func getData(query string, db *sql.DB) *sql.Rows {
    rows, err := db.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("SQL select error: ")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    return rows
}
```

That's why you're not able to read data

Comment: Yes, thanks, i forgot to remove it, so it just close conenction, after return :)